# Retain textarea information if page accidentally refreshes or capcha doesn't work

Tags: php, textarea, refresh, page-refresh

I have managed to find answers on the input areas for text and have that working. I have a contact form, two inputs - name & email - and a textarea for information.

Looking online I find answers to use this line of code in the value to retain the information if there is a page refresh -

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" value='<?php echo 
isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; ?>' required>
```

Although when I add the  value=''  to my text area it doesn't work like the others. I changed the names to match too.

Here is the physical page so you can see for yourself - idwithin.xyz/contact.php and I'll paste all my code below.

Thank you.

```
<div class="contactForm">
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" value='<?php echo 
isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; ?>' required>

<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" value='<?php echo 
isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>' required>

<textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Your Message" value='<?
```

php echo isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : ''; ?>' required>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add value="" to textareas, you render the value between the tags:

```
<textarea><?php echo isset($_POST['message']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']) : ''; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: So I add this between the tags to retain the information if the page accidentally refreshed? "<?php echo 
isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>"

Comment: If that's the way you retain that information, then yes. Btw, you could also deploy mechanism to prevent accidental refresh of page with modified form content.

Comment: What is deploy mechanism? Add that tag as a value in between the tags just shows me the html code in the text area box. It doens't help.

Comment: Well I mean "to deploy a mechanism" in javascript that would watch if anything in the form has changed, and if user tries to leave the page an alert is shown to him saying something like "You have modified this form data, are you sure you want to navigate away?" I'm sure you know this message. But his is another story. for the sake of your original question, use the code from your previous comment. I'll update my orignal answer with it...